# updating to @Angular/@latest

Tags: angular

We have a very big site that we are still running Angular2.0.0-beta.14 on.
My boss wants me to upgrade it to the latest Angular. Is there a quick way to change all the redundant files to the new version in my TS files as there are way to much files to do it all by hand. Also i don't know what all the new imports will be. An example being our app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {LoginComponent} from './loginpage'
import {DummyComponent} from './dummyComponent'
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router'
import {LandingPage}from'./landingPage'
import {DebtViewPage}from'./debtViewPage'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [LoginComponent,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/login-page', name : 'Login' , component : LoginComponent , 
     useAsDefault: true },
    {path:'/landing-page/...',name:'Landing',component:LandingPage}
])

export class AppComponent {

}
```

This is how it use to work in Angular2.0.0-beta14

How do i change this to latest Angular syntax. also do i have to update all these pages separately or is there a way i can update all of them at once.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I don't know of any tool that will do that for you. And just a heads up that this will be quite a task. In rc5 Angular added ngModule which requires that every component, directive, and pipe be added to an ngModule (Angular module.) Plus the router was changed before release. So a search/replace will work for some of the import changes, but the rest will require some manual processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool for upgrading your Angular App 
you can check below link it's check list for converting angular 2 app to angular 4. 
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Before following these directions, you'll need to migrate to Angular 2 Final. There are steps for rc4 and up here: https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/